# Redirect stderr and stdout to another file descriptor

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

`exec 6>&1` will copy file descriptor 1 onto 6.

But how can I copy both stderr and stdout (1 and 2)to file descriptor 6 ?

Comment: exec 1>./all.txt
exec 2>./all.txt

Answer (score 4):

Redirect stdout to 6 and stderr to stdout (so it will be further redirected to 6):

```
command >&6 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can redirect two files descriptors in one, but you can use two files descriptors pointing to one file

```
exec 1>./all.txt
exec 2>./all.txt
```

Comment: `bash` allows the special case of `&> ./all.txt` to redirect  stdout and stderr at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
command &>&6
```

---

```
&>filename  
    # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."  
    # This operator is now functional, as of Bash 4, final release.  
M>&N  
    # "M" is a file descriptor, which defaults to 1, if not set.  
    # "N" is another file descriptor.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `&>` does not allow you to duplicate two file descriptors into one; it only allows you to redirect to a file.